# Running `mvt-ios` outputs: "Error: Missing argument 'BACKUP_PATH'"

Tags: encryption

New to Linux/Ubuntu and I'm using Hirsute Hippo 21.04. I want to use the [Mobile Verification Toolkit](https://docs.mvt.re/en/latest/index.html).

These are the [instructions](https://docs.mvt.re/en/latest/ios/backup/check.html) I have:

> ### Decrypting a backup
>
> In case you have an encrypted backup, you will need to decrypt it first. This can be done with mvt-ios as well:
>
> ```
> $ mvt-ios decrypt-backup --help
> Usage: mvt-ios decrypt-backup [OPTIONS] BACKUP_PATH
>   Decrypt an encrypted iTunes backup
> Options:
>   -d, --destination TEXT  Path to the folder where to store the decrypted
>                           backup  [required]
>   -p, --password TEXT     Password to use to decrypt the backup (or, set
>                           MVT_IOS_BACKUP_PASSWORD environment variable)
>                           NOTE: This argument is mutually exclusive with
>                           arguments: [key_file].
>   -k, --key-file PATH     File containing raw encryption key to use to decrypt
>                           the backup NOTE: This argument is mutually exclusive
>                           with arguments: [password].
>   --help                  Show this message and exit.
> ```
>
> You can specify the password in the environment variable `MVT_IOS_BACKUP_PASSWORD`, or via command-line argument, or you can pass a key file. You need to specify a destination path where the decrypted backup will be stored. If a password cannot be found and no key file is specified, MVT will ask for a password. Following is an example usage of `decrypt-backup` sending the password via an environment variable:
>
> ```
> MVT_IOS_BACKUP_PASSWORD="mypassword" mvt-ios decrypt-backup -d /path/to/decrypted /path/to/backup
> ```
>
> ### Run `mvt-ios` on a Backup
>
> Once you have a decrypted backup available for analysis you can use the `check-backup` subcommand:
>
> ```
> $ mvt-ios check-backup --help
> Usage: mvt-ios check-backup [OPTIONS] BACKUP_PATH
>   Extract artifacts from an iTunes backup
> Options:
>   -i, --iocs PATH     Path to indicators file
>   -o, --output PATH   Specify a path to a folder where you want to store JSON
>                       results
>   -f, --fast          Avoid running time/resource consuming features
>   -l, --list-modules  Print list of available modules and exit
>   -m, --module TEXT   Name of a single module you would like to run instead of
>                       all
>   --help              Show this message and exit.
> ```
>
> Following is a basic usage of `check-backup`:
>
> ```
> mvt-ios check-backup --output /path/to/output/ /path/to/backup/udid/
> ```
>
> This command will create a few JSON files containing the results from the extraction. If you do not specify a `--output` option, `mvt-ios`  will just process the data without storing results on disk.
>
> Through the `--iocs` argument you can specify a STIX2 file defining a list of malicious indicators to check against the records extracted from the backup by mvt. Any matches will be highlighted in the terminal output as well as saved in the output folder using a *"_detected"* suffix to the JSON file name.

I'm having trouble running the decryption command in terminal.
I get the following:

```
a@a:~/Peg/mvt$ mvt-ios decrypt-backup -d ~/Peg/iPhonedecryp
Usage: mvt-ios decrypt-backup [OPTIONS] BACKUP_PATH
Try 'mvt-ios decrypt-backup --help' for help.

Error: Missing argument 'BACKUP_PATH'.
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried with the full path?

Comment: Hi folks many thanks for the suggestions. Sorted it and have  generated json files.

Comment: You can answer your own question (and later accept it) with how you "sorted it".

Comment: Many thanks ChanganAuto

Comment: I have run decrypted JSON files with pythonstix2 and have an output i do not understand.